# How to be able to 'show' a QWidget from within a QMainWindow (pyside)?

Tags: python, pyside

I have not a lot experience with complex pyside applications, so please be gentle...

Within a `QMainWindow` application I am initializing a new `QWidget` class which contains checkboxes, input fields, dropdown menus etc. to configure some parameters. Now, in the main code I write:

```
def myconfigure(self):

    configure_widget = ConfigureWidget()
    configure_widget.show()
    # wait until user makes input and presses OK or Cancel or ...
    self.so_somtething_with_content_of(configure_widget)
```

When the code executes, the widget is created for a very brief time only and vanishes immedeately. How to make the code execution 'stop' in the main application until the user presses 'OK' or 'Cancel' (or anything) in the configure-widget?

**Addendum:** 
I need the main code to stop at this point until the user makes his input (chooses entry from dropdown box, checks checksboxes, chooses directories, whatever). Otherwise, the main code does not know how to proceed. I could use an endless `while` loop, but this would not be very efficient...

Comment: [These code examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt/qdialog.html#code-examples) might be relevant.

Comment: QWidget does not seem to have a `raise` method.

Comment: the object get garbage collected after the method ends, since you don't hold a reference to it any more. Add `self.configure_widget`. To make it block( stop code execution) you should make it a QDialog instead of a Qwidget. And show it with exec

Comment: @M4rtini: Thanks, that works. But I guess this is not the only solution...?

Comment: Probably not the only solution, but i would guess it is the easiest

Comment: Sorry, your solution does not work - I forgot to mention important information. The main code HAS to stop because it needs user input at this stage, provided by the user with the QWidget...

Comment: @Alex as i said, use a QDialog with exec to block further code execution in the main app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54353/discussion-between-alex-and-m4rtini).